# Why doesn't the trigger update the column value in an Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I am using **oracle 11gR1** database. The problem is, I have a table which script is given below :-

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
  ID       NUMBER, 
  CATEGORY VARCHAR2(19),
  CODE     VARCHAR2(20),
  URI      VARCHAR2(160));
```

Now my aim is to **create a trigger** which updates `URI` column every time with below calculated string when row in the `TEST` table **either getting inserted or updated.**

`URI` column will be calculated using `'uri://cateogry/code'`. So I created a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST_URI_UPDATE_TRIG
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF CATEGORY, CODE ON TEST
FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; --added later after getting error(mutating, trigger/function may not see it error) during insertion
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-------------EXECUTING TRIGGER----------');

    UPDATE TEST
       SET URI = 'uri://' || upper(:NEW.CATEGORY) || '/' || upper(:NEW.CODE)
     WHERE ID = :NEW.id;

    --Just to print the output
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OLD VALUE IS : ' || :OLD.ID || '   EXECUTING TRIGGER ID IS : ' || :NEW.ID);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OLD VALUE IS : ' || UPPER(:OLD.CATEGORY) || '   EXECUTING TRIGGER ID IS : ' || upper(:NEW.CATEGORY));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OLD VALUE IS : ' || UPPER(:OLD.CODE) || '   EXECUTING TRIGGER ID IS : ' || upper(:NEW.CODE));
    COMMIT; --added later after getting error(mutating, trigger/function may not see it error) during insertion
  END;
/
```

Values will be inserted only in `ID, CATEGORY, CODE` columns not in `URI` column.

Now if I am inserting or updating values in to TEST table.

The trigger does not update `URI` column of `TEST` table (don't know why). Even though values are getting printed by `DBMS_OUTPUT` print message.

I tried to do using `VIRTUAL COLUMN` in Oracle, but that doesn't satisfied my requirement, because I want **`URI` column values must be present in Database which is not possible with it.**

So could you please any body help me and suggest any way to do it.

Comment: According to the docs, you'd rather use a before trigger: change the trigger flavor statement to `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF CATEGORY, CODE ON TEST` and the update statement to `:NEW.URI = 'uri://'||upper(:NEW.CATEGORY)||'/'||upper(:NEW.CODE);`. Drop the autonomous transaction pragma.

Comment: Agreed, use a before trigger and remove the autonomous transaction and commit which will come back to bite you

Comment: @collapsar thanks alot, yes this is what i wanted

Comment: @collapsar i also wanted to know why it is not updating uri column using above trigger without changing anything in trigger script. am i doing wrong any thing please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a before row trigger. then change the URI value as below

```
:NEW.URI := 'uri://'||upper(:NEW.CATEGORY)||'/'||upper(:NEW.CODE);
```

No need to select or update. The values are available using the :NEW pseudo column,

Comment: Thanks alot for that much of quick reply with an exact solution.